# magento database file not importing completely

Tags: database, mysql, importexport

we are trying to move the magento site from one domain to another domain.

but the database filoe size is 800mb.

we are using cpanel.

when we are trying to import the database, its not uploading completely.

lot of tables are missing  after importing.

is there any way to import 800mb database file completely

thanks in advance

Comment: frinds any error for importing data

Comment: i am not geting any error, but tables are missing after importing....

Comment: i have ans for question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have shell access to the server? If so, you can likely upload the file to it (via FTP or rsync), and then use the MySQL CLI tools to import. Or, if you have remote access to the MySQL server enabled for your IP, you can import directly through your local CLI tool.

Here's an example of what I would do regularly:

### MySQL CLI

```
mysql -u user -p your_magento_db -h server.com < database.sql
```

### rsync/SSH/MySQL CLI

```
rsync -avPz ./database.sql user@server.com:/path/to/temp/location/
ssh user@server.com
[login]
mysql -u user -p your_magento_db < /path/to/temp/location/database.sql
[enter password]
```

The first example requires that you have remote access allowed to your MySQL server, and also the CLI tools installed locally on your machine.

The second example is used when you need to push the database up to the remote server, then you log into it and use the CLI tool there to make the import.

---

Note that the above command syntax might change depending on your environment, but this is generally the best way to avoid large transfer limits over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

it is because your database has a foreign key constraint. Follow below steps before importing

1) Open the exported sql file of your database and add following sql query at the begining

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

2) Goto the end of the file and add

```
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

This should work. It will disable foreign key check while importing and then will reenable it.

Comment: seems itas problem with hosting. its not allowing for large database, we are using shared hosting. thanks for your support.